# Data Validation code: specify target range

Tags: vba, excel, validation, optimization

I have an excel worksheet with a table where column headers are time intervals and row headers are people's names. Each cell in the middle has a dropdown list. I inputted the code below so that the user can select more than one option from the dropdown within each cell.

The code works fine however the entire sheet is being affected by it rather than just the target range. For example, when I try to edit a cell in the column header just by hitting backspace on the cell and inputting new text...the cell formats like this: "6:30am, 7:30am" or "old value, new value"

```
Option Explicit

 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 ' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel

  Dim Oldvalue As String
  Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Range("E10:V600") Is Nothing Then
GoTo Exitsub
Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
    If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
    Else
        Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I can avoid this by right clicking on the cell, hitting clear contents, exiting the cell, then clicking the cell again to edit it. But I want to prevent this issue. 
Any idea where my code went wrong? The target range is the correct range of cells I need the code to work on. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line: `If Target.Range("E10:V600") Is Nothing Then` is not correct syntax. Or maybe the syntax compiles, but it will not produce what you want.

Change it to this: `If Not Instersect(Target, Me.Range("E10:V600")) Is Nothing Then`

So full code becomes
ption Explicit

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     ' To Select Multiple Items from a Drop Down List in Excel

    Dim Oldvalue As String
    Dim Newvalue As String

    If Not Instersect(Target, Me.Range("E10:V600")) Is Nothing Then

        If Len(Target.Value) Then 

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Newvalue = Target.Value

            Application.Undo

            Oldvalue = Target.Value

            If Oldvalue = "" Then
                Target.Value = Newvalue
            Else
                Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
            End If

            Application.EnableEvents = True   

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Do I also have to change the `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`?

Comment: thank you for the code. Now within the specified range I am not able to clear contents or hit backspace to clear the cell. Instead the cell formats itself as "old value, , ," each time I try to clear it. Any work around for this?

Comment: Hi @scottholtzman, follow up question- does something about the len function in your code not accommodate dragging and dropping cell values over a range of cells >1? It gives me an error each time I try to drag and drop or copy into more than one cell. I hit debug and exit out of the code module and it runs fine, but I'm not sure why this happens

Comment: @SRag - Yes. It does because the Target is more than one cell. You can place something like `Or Target.Rows > 1 Or Target.Columns > 1`, but this will fail if you clear more than one cell at a time. You'll have to figure out the logic for that. Maybe an `If Then Else If` type of statement.